# How to interleave the bytes of 3 avx registers in c++

Tags: c++, intrinsics, avx, avx2

Hi following snipped:

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    uint8_t a[] = {0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21};
    uint8_t b[] = {1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22};
    uint8_t c[] = {2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23};

    auto as = _mm256_loadu_epi8(a);
    auto bs = _mm256_loadu_epi8(b);
    auto cs = _mm256_loadu_epi8(c);
    // uint8_t result[32] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11...}

    return 0;
}
```

I played a lot with pack/unpack/shuffle/permutate but did not get my desired result.
I want a result that contains all values in increasing order (0, 1, 2, 3...), so basically I want to interleave all three input arrays. Has anybody a solution for that?

Comment: Just so we're clear: Your example vectors are 8 shorts = 128 bit but you load them with 256 bit instructions. I assume you want a routine with full 256 bit vectors

Comment: Yes, this is just to simplify things. Actually I want to convert yuv to rgb and need the interleaving there for the rgb registers into memory. Basically the values only use lower 8 bits of the short.

Comment: So the input data are 3 `unsigned short` arrays where the upper 8 bit per short are zero. And the output is one 24 bit integer per input? Or 3 x 16 bit interleaved?

Comment: I refined the example. Maybe it's clearer now

Comment: My gut instinct is that after the `unpacklo/hi`, there won't be anything better than a large set of `_mm256_shuffle_epi8` with several sets of shuffle vectors. Converting into 32 bit RGBA with an unused alpha channel would be much faster

Comment: Are `as`, `bs`, `cs` actually already in registers (e.g., result of another operation) or do they come from memory? And do you need the result in registers for further operations or only stored to memory? (This influences at what point you can join/split the upper/lower 128bit lanes of the registers).

Comment: The problem sounds like a transpose of a matrix held in avx registers. What is intended usage for this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version based on `_mm256_shuffle_epi8`. The issue is that you cannot shuffle across 128 bit lanes. Therefore, to have the required information in both lanes, you have to do a broadcast.

Here I assume that I can read beyond the end of the required values (10 byte per vector). Substitute with other sequences to achieve the same with more careful memory accesses as required.

```cpp
auto a_lo = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*) a);
auto b_lo = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*) b);
auto c_lo = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*) c);

auto as = _mm256_broadcastsi128_si256(a_lo);
auto bs = _mm256_broadcastsi128_si256(b_lo);
auto cs = _mm256_broadcastsi128_si256(c_lo);
```

Now we can set up masks to put bytes into their individual positions. Other values are set to zero. Note that the last two bytes are always zero since 32 isn't divisible by 3.

```cpp
auto mask_axx = _mm256_setr_epi8(
        /* first lane */
        0, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 2, -1, -1, 3, -1, -1, 4, -1, -1, 5,
        /* second lane */
        -1, -1, 6, -1, -1, 7, -1, -1, 8, -1, -1, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1);
auto mask_xbx = _mm256_setr_epi8(
        /* first lane */
        -1, 0, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 2, -1, -1, 3, -1, -1, 4, -1, -1,
        /* second lane */
        5, -1, -1, 6, -1, -1, 7, -1, -1, 8, -1, -1, 9, -1, -1, -1);
auto mask_xxc = _mm256_setr_epi8(
        /* first lane */
        -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 2, -1, -1, 3, -1, -1, 4, -1,
        /* second lane */
        -1, 5, -1, -1, 6, -1, -1, 7, -1, -1, 8, -1, -1, 9, -1, -1);
```

Now all that's left is to apply the shuffle, then OR the results.

```cpp
auto axx = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(as, mask_axx);
auto xbx = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(bs, mask_xbx);
auto xxc = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(cs, mask_xxc);
auto abc = _mm256_or_si256(axx, xbx);
abc = _mm256_or_si256(abc, xxc);
```

Again, the last two bytes are zero. So in a loop this would advance 10 bytes in the `a`, `b`, and `c` arrays and then 30 byte in the output array.

A half-width version with 5 output pixels over 15 byte works the same except that the `mask_axx` is `-1` in the last position of its single lane.

### Full loop

Here is a full conversion function.

At one point I use an implicit cast from `uint8_t` to `uint16_t`, so we have to be careful to use unsigned values for the individual bytes to avoid accidental sign extension.

```cpp
void interleave_abc(std::uint8_t* out, const std::uint8_t* a,
        const std::uint8_t* b, const  std::uint8_t* c,
        std::ptrdiff_t n)
{
```

Since we will have to deal with the tail elements, it helps to wrap the main computation in a lambda. Lambdas are very strongly inlined so this will not have any overhead.

```cpp
    auto pack256 = [=](std::ptrdiff_t i, __m256i mask_axx,
            __m256i mask_xbx, __m256i mask_xxc) {
        auto a_lo = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*) (a + i));
        auto b_lo = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*) (b + i));
        auto c_lo = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*) (c + i));
        auto as = _mm256_broadcastsi128_si256(a_lo);
        auto bs = _mm256_broadcastsi128_si256(b_lo);
        auto cs = _mm256_broadcastsi128_si256(c_lo);
        auto axx = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(as, mask_axx);
        auto xbx = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(bs, mask_xbx);
        auto xxc = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(cs, mask_xxc);
        auto abc = _mm256_or_si256(axx, xbx);
        return _mm256_or_si256(abc, xxc);
    };
```

Which we can then use for the main loop.

```cpp
    const auto mask_axx = _mm256_setr_epi8(
            /* first lane */
            0, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 2, -1,
            -1, 3, -1, -1, 4, -1, -1, 5,
            /* second lane */
            -1, -1, 6, -1, -1, 7, -1, -1,
            8, -1, -1, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1);
    const auto mask_xbx = _mm256_setr_epi8(
            -1, 0, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 2,
            -1, -1, 3, -1, -1, 4, -1, -1,
            5, -1, -1, 6, -1, -1, 7, -1,
            -1, 8, -1, -1, 9, -1, -1, -1);
    const auto mask_xxc = _mm256_setr_epi8(
            -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1,
            2, -1, -1, 3, -1, -1, 4, -1,
            -1, 5, -1, -1, 6, -1, -1, 7,
            -1, -1, 8, -1, -1, 9, -1, -1);
    std::ptrdiff_t i;
    for(i = 0; i + 16 <= n; i += 10) {
        auto abc = pack256(i, mask_axx, mask_xbx, mask_xxc);
        _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*) (out + 3 * i), abc);
    }
```

Handling the tail is … bothersome. Using partial loads and stores generates many different cases for what I assume are about 30 CPU cycles when handled in a trivial loop. That isn't worth it in my opinion unless short sequences are a common occurrence and the number of samples can be constant-propagated. Instead, we go for something different. First we start by getting the special case out of the way that we have fewer than 16 bytes per input channel.

```cpp
    if(n < 16) {
        for(; i < n; ++i) {
            std::uint16_t ab = b[i];
            ab = ab << 8 | a[i];
            *((std::uint16_t*) (out + 3 * i)) = ab;
            out[3 * i + 2] = c[i];
        }
        return;
    }
```

For cases where we have enough samples, we can do a similar loop to the main loop, but going backwards from the end and using the tail elements of the vectors. The results will partially overlap with the ones we already computed but the number of cycles used for this (and lines of code) is reasonably low. There are at most two iterations of this loop to deal with up to 15 tail elements.

```cpp
    const auto tailmask_axx = _mm256_setr_epi8(
            -1, -1, 6, -1, -1, 7, -1, -1,
            8, -1, -1, 9, -1, -1, 10, -1,
            -1, 11, -1, -1, 12, -1, -1, 13,
            -1, -1, 14, -1, -1, 15, -1, -1);
    const auto tailmask_xbx = _mm256_setr_epi8(
            5, -1, -1, 6, -1, -1, 7, -1,
            -1, 8, -1, -1, 9, -1, -1, 10,
            -1, -1, 11, -1, -1, 12, -1, -1,
            13, -1, -1, 14, -1, -1, 15, -1);
    const auto tailmask_xxc = _mm256_setr_epi8(
            -1, 5, -1, -1, 6, -1, -1, 7,
            -1, -1, 8, -1, -1, 9, -1, -1,
            10, -1, -1, 11, -1, -1, 12, -1,
            -1, 13, -1, -1, 14, -1, -1, 15);
    for(std::ptrdiff_t j = n; j >= i; j -= 10) {
        auto abc = pack256(j - 16, tailmask_axx, tailmask_xbx,
                tailmask_xxc);
        _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*) (out + 3 * j - 32), abc);
    }
}
```